# How to use two gestureRecognizers simultaniously

Tags: iphone, image, animation, drag, uigesturerecognizer

Within my view I've got several images. All of those images are linked to a LongPressGestureRecognizer and a PanGestureRecognizer.

When a user Press and holds (LongPressGesture) the image animates (wiggles). When the users drags the image ,after the LongPressGesture takes in place, the animation pauzes. When the user stops dragging the animation continues.

Is there a way to use two gestureRecognizers simultaniously so that my animation doesn't pauzes when a user drags the image?

Help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this methods : 
`- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer;`

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However the problem still isn't solved. Any suggestions about what to implement inside this method?